# Invalid return property value in Vue 3

Tags: typescript, vuejs2, vuejs3

I'm making pagination using Vue, it was working fine yesterday but today it encountered a bug,

I have assigned the totalPage that the api returns but it no longer accepts that value to calculate the totalPage... Here is my code:

**View**

```js
<template>
  <!-- Pagination -->
        <span class="flex col-span-4 mt-2 sm:mt-auto sm:justify-end">
          <nav aria-label="Table navigation">
            <ul class="inline-flex items-center">
              <a-pagination
                v-if="!loading"
                @change="pagination"
                v-model:current="current"
                :total="totalPage"
                show-less-items
              />
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </span>
</template>
```

**Script**

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
const totalPage = ref<number>();
const current = ref(1);
async function getFile(page = 1) {
  try {
    const fileData = await request.get("api/admin/file/list", {
      params: {
        page,
        limit: 7,
        name: searchName.value.trim(),
        status: stateStatus.value,
        mimetype: typeFile.value,
        lte_size: endSize.value,
        gte_size: startSize.value,
      },
    });
    files.value = fileData.data.data;

    totalPage.value = fileData.data.count;
    console.log("Tổng trang:",totalPage.value) //Log the correct results
    loading.value = false;
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
  
  onMounted(async () => {
    await getFile();
});

//Tính phân trang
async function pagination(pageNumber: number) {
  current.value = pageNumber;
    files.value = [];
    await getFile(pageNumber);
}
</script>
```

Hope to get help from everyone, thanks a lot